# Fixing unsafe implementation of HostnameVerifier

Tags: android, android-security

I am getting a warning in the google dashboard saying I need to fix the way I am accepting self signed certificates. The issue is that the app I am working on needs to be able to connect to multipul self signed certs, and the urls to the servers are entered manualy by the user.

The code I currently have is this

```
        try {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier { hostname, session -> true }
            val ssl_context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")

            ssl_context.init(null, arrayOf<X509TrustManager>(object : X509TrustManager {
                @Throws(CertificateException::class)
                override fun checkClientTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) {
                }

                @Throws(CertificateException::class)
                override fun checkServerTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) {
                }

                override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate?> {
                    return arrayOfNulls(0)
                }
            }), SecureRandom())
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(
                ssl_context.socketFactory
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) { 
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Is there a safer way to accept any type of self signed cert?

Comment: If the multiple self-signed certs are known by you, you could check for them specifically. If you are saying that the user is hitting arbitrary networks, and they have arbitrary self-signed certs... then there is nothing that you can do AFAIK, and Google isn't going to be all that happy.

Comment: @CommonsWare the users enter a address/url of a server they have purchased from us. This is custom hardware and each one has a self signed cert. Is there a way for android to ask for the self signed cert from the server and then add it to a Trust Manager.

Comment: "Is there a way for android to ask for the self signed cert from the server and then add it to a Trust Manager" -- not on modern versions of Android. Rather than pure self-signed certs, you could use ones issued by a Web service and backed by a private certificate authority. Then, the Android app could validate that the certificate chain includes your private CA.

Comment: Note that depending on the scale of your service, 'your private CA' might be just a private key and OpenSSL config file you store (and backup!) on an offline machine. Alternatively, build a custom APK for each client that is setup to trust their server and it's self-signed cert.